# Oracle Linux 6 download files?

Tags: system-installation, oracle-linux

I want to download Oracle Linux 6 for basic use to install on my laptop to use oracle 11g r2 database since this is one of only few Linux distros which is supported. When I go to the downloads section I these are the options:

```
-Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 for x86_64 (64 Bit)
-Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 Boot iso image for x86_64 (64 bit)
-Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 UEK Boot ISO image for x86_64 (64 bit)
-Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 source DVD 1
-Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 source DVD 2
```

I want to just burn it onto a DVD and then install it on my laptop so which is the right download(s) I need? As well, I know UEK is the unbreakable kernel but is this mandatory to install or optional?

Normally I would download them all and try, but I'm very limited on my bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but the answer is:

- **Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 for x86_64 (64 Bit)**: The basic DVD with all packages that a installation requires. It comes with the "minimal" set of packages plus some groups like "Desktop Environment", "Development Tools".
- **Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 Boot iso image for x86_64 (64 bit)**: It is just a boot image, an you will need to have a package mirror inside your network to complete the instalation using this media
- **Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 UEK Boot ISO image for x86_64 (64 bit)**. It's the same as boot iso, but it comes with the UEK(unbreakable) Kernel variation. The difference here are some featueres that Oracle enabled like seting up your root filesystem with btrfs using UEK kernel with this media. You will need the same network repository/mirror to finish the installation.
- **Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 source DVD 1 & 2** - Source code packages. Just usefull for Linux devs

From Oracle Linux 5.6 and newer, and Oracle Linux 6 and newer, UEK is the default kernel, but the Red Hat compatible kernel will be installed as well.

Answer (score 0):

From their names, I assume that "Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 Boot iso image for x86_64" is the normal CD/DVD installer. Just download that, burn it onto a CD or DVD and boot from it.

Comment: that is what I was thinking, but the file is only 200mb, do you think that is right?

Comment: @user44393 it could be yes, It depends on how the installer works, if it downloads extra files during the install or if it just comes with a small selection of bundled software. This is just a guess though, I;ve never tried it.